# Which is the better way to return multiple DataTable in C#

Tags: methods, datatable, return, dataset

I need to call a method to return three datatable

Method1

```
public DataTable[] ReturnMultipleTable(string query)
{
    DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
    DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
    DataTable table3 = new DataTable();
    // do something
    return new DataTable[] { table1, table2, table3 };
}
```

Method2

```
public DataSet ReturnMultipleTable(string query)
{
     DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
     DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
     DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
     DataTable table3 = new DataTable();
     // do something
     dataset.Tables.Add(table1);
     dataset.Tables.Add(table2);
     dataset.Tables.Add(table3);
     return dataset;
}
```

Method3

```
public void ReturnMultipleTable(string query, out DataTable table1, out DataTable table2, out DataTable table3)
{
    DataTable tb1 = new DataTable();
    DataTable tb2 = new DataTable();
    DataTable tb3 = new DataTable();
    // do something
    table1 = tb1;
    table2 = tb2;
    table3 = tb3;
}
```

which way is the better coding using less resource???

Comment: Did you consider to use Tuples? See [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple?view=net-7.0)